# Problem With Running App on my Android Device

Tags: c#, android, google-play

Im trying to make A 2d Platformer and i Exported it to my Device and I get this error

```
Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;
  at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleDispatcher$DispatcherActivityCallback.onActivityCreated (LifecycleDispatcher.java:73)
  at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated (Application.java:368)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityCreated (Activity.java:1371)
  at android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:1653)
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate (UnityPlayerActivity.java:35)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8290)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8269)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1384)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3657)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3813)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2308)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7898)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

i also tried uploading it to the google playstore and i get this error again

this is my first time making an app anyone know why this happens?

i Tried to see what the Problem is But there is nothing online that i found to help.

Comment: Open the APK file of your app in Jadx and check if the class `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` is included in the Java/Kotlin/DEX part of your app.

Comment: @Robert Im using Android Studio Is there anyway i could do that in there? Thanks,

Comment: Android Studio is for building apps. Jadx is for decompiling apps. First check the APK file if the class is present. If not something is wrong with your gradle configuration of the app.

Comment: @Robert Thank you Where do i download JadX ive looked online and theres loads of websites with it, Do they have an official website i can download it from

Comment: Google first result: https://github.com/skylot/jadx

Comment: @Robert I got Jadx And looked and It isnt There. What should i do now? Thanks,

Comment: That class belongs to an older Android support library. If it is missing this could mean that something is wrong with your garden build script especially the used libraries. Or another possibility is that your project has already been migrated to androidx library the successor of the v4 support lib and one library is still requesting the old library, which could mean that there is an incontinency in the used libraries. May be because of using an outdated tutorial.

Comment: @Robert thank you for your help i will look into this further to see if i can fix it